# Provide refactoring code ( method for filter )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I wrote a function to filter entries on my site, but it looks quite cumbersome. And I am sure that this code can be written easier and less cumbersome, I will be very grateful for any help. Below is the function itself.

```
def search
  if current_user.tutor?    
    if params[:subject_id] == ""
      @help_requests = HelpRequest.all.order(created_at: params[:direction] == "1" ? :desc : :asc)
    else
      @help_requests = HelpRequest.where("subject_id IN (?)", params[:subject_id]).order(created_at: params[:direction] == "1" ? :desc : :asc)
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render}
    end
  else
    @help_requests = HelpRequest.list_of_request params:[subject_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can move both `respond_to do |format|` outside of the main `if` statement while still in the search method.

Comment: Thank you! @Jake

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To save you from writing it twice, you can move both `respond_to do |format|` outside of the `if` statement as one:

```
def search
  if current_user.tutor?    
    if params[:subject_id] == ""
      @help_requests = HelpRequest.all.order(created_at: params[:direction] == "1" ? :desc : :asc)
    else
      @help_requests = HelpRequest.where("subject_id IN (?)", params[:subject_id]).order(created_at: params[:direction] == "1" ? :desc : :asc)
    end
  else
    @help_requests = HelpRequest.list_of_request params:[subject_id]
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render}
  end
end
```

Another thing to try is shortening `@help_requests = HelpRequest` to `help_requests` this:

```
def search
  if current_user.tutor?    
    if params[:subject_id] == ""
      help_requests.all.order(created_at: params[:direction] == "1" ? :desc : :asc)
    else
      help_requests.where("subject_id IN (?)", params[:subject_id]).order(created_at: params[:direction] == "1" ? :desc : :asc)
    end
  else
    help_requests.list_of_request params:[subject_id]
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render}
  end
end

private

  def help_requests
    @help_requests = HelpRequest
  end
```

Comment: @ДенисСаенко You're welcome, please remember that saying thanks is not necessary (and is not encouraged) to be left as a comment. An upvote on a comment or answer is all you need to leave to show your appreciation.